# read_csv won't read from a file list and specified directory

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an issue with using Python read_csv in a function. If I use the following code, there is no issue. It will read the two files which I can then append to a single dataframe output:

```
directory = r"\\*my directory*"   
files1 = ['001 Data.txt', '002 Data.txt']

def read_data(directory, files):
    list_ = []
    for file in files:           
        df = pd.read_csv(directory + '\\' + file, sep='\t', header=0)
        ...do stuff... 
        list_.append()
    return list_

df_mct20 = read_data(directory, files1)  # This will generate my list which I can then concatenate
df_final = pd.concat(df_mct20)
```

The above code works fine. However, if I call this exact "read_data()" function in a for loop, I get the "No such file or directory" error:

```
files2 = ['003 Data.txt', '004 Data.txt']

for file in files2:    
    df2 = read_data(directory, file)  # The error shows up here "No such file or directory"
    ...want to do stuff...
```

I've tried a number of things and can't seem to get it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second input of your function has to be a list of filenames. So you cannot loop in a series of strings into the function itself.

You either need to re-write your function to just take in one filename at a time, or load in your files2 as a list, and not loop the filenames in files2 in.

Comment: Thank you Cliff, and much appreciated~